# Signature does not match in Amazon Web Services

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am writing a PHP code for AMAZON WEB SERVICES. This is my code.

```
<?php

function amazonEncode($text) {
    $encodedText = "";
    $j = strlen($text);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
        $c = substr($text, $i, 1);
        if (!preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9-_.~]/", $c)) {
            $encodedText .= sprintf("%%%02X", ord($c));
        } else {
            $encodedText .= $c;
        }
    }
    return $encodedText;
}

function amazonSign($url, $secretAccessKey) {
    // 0. Append Timestamp parameter
    $url .= "&Timestamp=" . gmdate("Y-m-dTH:i:sZ");
    // 1a. Sort the UTF-8 query string components by parameter name
    $urlParts = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($urlParts["query"], $queryVars);
    ksort($queryVars);
    // 1b. URL encode the parameter name and values
    $encodedVars = array();
    foreach ($queryVars as $key => $value) {
        $encodedVars[amazonEncode($key)] = amazonEncode($value);
    }
    // 1c. 1d. Reconstruct encoded query
    $encodedQueryVars = array();
    foreach ($encodedVars as $key => $value) {
        $encodedQueryVars[] = $key . "=" . $value;
    }
    $encodedQuery = implode("&", $encodedQueryVars);
    // 2. Create the string to sign
    $stringToSign = "GET";
    $stringToSign .= "n" . strtolower($urlParts["host"]);
    $stringToSign .= "n" . $urlParts["path"];
    $stringToSign .= "n" . $encodedQuery;
    // 3. Calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with the string you just created,
    //    your Secret Access Key as the key, and SHA256 as the hash algorithm.
    if (function_exists("hash_hmac")) {
        $hmac = hash_hmac("sha256", $stringToSign, $secretAccessKey, TRUE);
    } elseif (function_exists("mhash")) {
        $hmac = mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $stringToSign, $secretAccessKey);
    } else {
        die("No hash function available!");
    }
    // 4. Convert the resulting value to base64
    $hmacBase64 = base64_encode($hmac);
    // 5. Use the resulting value as the value of the Signature request parameter
    // (URL encoded as per step 1b)
    $url .= "&Signature=" . amazonEncode($hmacBase64);
    echo $url;
}

$url = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=something&AssociateTag=something&Operation=ItemSearch&Keywords=Mustang&SearchIndex=Blended&Condition=Collectible&Timestamp=2016-08-08T12%3A00%3A00Z&Version=2013-08-01';
$SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key';
$url = amazonSign($url, $SECRET_KEY);
?>
```

This code returns me a URL. I use that URL inside my browser so that I can get my search results but using that URL gives me this error.

> SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I am using these as `AWSAccessKeyId` and `SECRET_KEY`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably `$stringToSign .= "n"` should be `$stringToSign .= "\n"` but this might not be the only problem. If you use the [official PHP SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) from Amazon instead of relying on custom scripts you'll have less issues.

Comment: Hi. I changed it but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is usually a mistyped Access Key or Secret Access Key.
or the issue may be non-UTF-8 encoded string. Once i UTF-8 encoded it, the error will disappeared. 
or if you sending a metadata with an empty value,than it will not work.
or if you not providing the Content-Length parameter than also such kind of issue can happen.